# What's the meaning of the following code?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, inline-assembly, compare-and-swap

There is a CAS code below which can handle just int type,I know the function of CAS but I don't know the details shown below.

```
inline int CAS(unsigned long *mem,unsigned long newval,unsigned long oldval)
{
    __typeof (*mem) ret;
    __asm __volatile ("lock; cmpxchgl %2, %1"
    : "=a" (ret), "=m" (*mem)
    : "r" (newval), "m" (*mem), "0" (oldval));
    return (int) ret;
}
```

I know there should be five parameters mapped to %0,%1,%2,%3,%4 because there are five parameters in input/output field

I also know that `"=a"` means using `eax` register,`"=m"` means using memory address,`"r"` means using any register

But I don't understand what the "0" means.

I don't understand why "cmpxchgl" only use two parameters %2, %1 instead of three?

It should use three params as the CAS function.

Where can I get all the infimation about the inline c asm?I need a complete tutorial.

Comment: For the inline asm, read the gcc manual. About how `cmpxchgl` works, read the instruction set reference. That said `"0"` means use same place as argument 0 (which is `eax` in this case), and `cmpxchgl` uses `eax` implicitly, that's why it only takes 2 arguments and that's why operands are fixed as `"=a"` and `"0"`. Also note gcc has portable builtins, you shouldn't use assembly for this.

Comment: In addition to @Jester 's excellent response, [here's](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html) the link to the docs for gcc's inline asm.  Also, essentially every time you use the "lock" prefix, you probably need the "memory" clobber (which this code does not have) to help avoid very subtle timing bugs.  Oh yes, and this should clobber "cc" as well.  Another reason to use builtins...

Comment: Very thanks to @Jester and @ David Wohlferd ,the information you provided helps me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

`%2` is `newval`, `%1` is `*mem`

with `"0" (oldval)`, and the first register occur is `"=a"`, means that  `oldval` is stored in `eax`.

So `cmpxchgl %2, %1"` means `cmpxchgl newval, *mem"`(while `oldval` in `eax`), which checks `eax`(value of oldval) whether equals `*mem`, if equal, change value of `*mem` to `newval`.